# Date diff in hive and the difference should be in hh:mm:ss

Tags: date, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am trying to find the difference between two dates in successive rows. I am using the windowing functions in hive i.e, `lag`.

But the difference i.e., the output should be in the format `hh:mm:ss`.

For eg:

- Date 1 is `2017-08-15 02:00:32`
- Date 2 is `2017-08-15 02:00:20`

Output should be:

> 00:00:12

The query I tried with:

```
select from_unixtime(column_name),
(lag(unix_timestamp(from_unixtime(column_name)),1,0)
over(partition by column_name)-
unix_timestamp(from_unixtime(column_name))) as Duration from table_name;
```

But this returns the output as `12` (in the above example).

## Update

I have stored the column in the table with bigint datatype. The time is in epoch format. We are converting it to readable date by using from_unixtime in our query. Sample values in timestamp

1502802618
1502786788

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer will be relevant as long as the times difference is less than 24 hours

```
hive> with t as (select 1502802618 as ts1,1502786788 as ts2)
    > select  from_unixtime(to_unix_timestamp('0001-01-01 00:00:00')+(ts1 - ts2))  as diff
    > from    t
    > ;
OK
diff
0001-01-01 04:23:50
```

---

```
hive> with t as (select 1502802618 as ts1,1502786788 as ts2)
    > select  substr(from_unixtime(to_unix_timestamp('0001-01-01 00:00:00')+(ts1 - ts2)),12)   as diff
    > from    t
    > ;
OK
diff
04:23:50
```

Answer (score 2):

```
hive> with t as (select 1502802618 as ts1,1502786788 as ts2)
    > select  printf('%02d:%02d:%02d',(ts1 - ts2) div 3600,((ts1 - ts2) % 3600) div 60,((ts1 - ts2) % 3600) % 60) as diff
    > from    t
    > ;
OK
diff
04:23:50
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer will be relevant as long as the times difference is less than 24 hours

```
hive> with t as (select timestamp '2017-08-15 02:00:32' as ts1,timestamp '2017-08-15 02:00:20' as ts2)
    > select  ts1 - ts2   as diff
    > from    t
    > ;
OK
diff
0 00:00:12.000000000
```

Given Timestamps

```
hive> with t as (select timestamp '2017-08-15 02:00:32' as ts1,timestamp '2017-08-15 02:00:20' as ts2)
    > select  split(ts1 - ts2,'[ .]')[1]  as diff
    > from    t
    > ;
OK
diff
00:00:12
```

Given strings

```
hive> with t as (select '2017-08-15 02:00:32' as ts1,'2017-08-15 02:00:20' as ts2)
    > select  split(cast(ts1 as timestamp) - cast(ts2 as timestamp),'[ .]')[1]  as diff
    > from    t
    > ;
OK
diff
00:00:12
```

Comment: I tried to execute your queries but it throws the error "No matching method for class org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDFOPMinus with (timestamp, timestamp)". Just to give more information about the table schema the column I have stored in bigint and it is in epoch timestamp.

Comment: This a tested code. Apparently your Hive version does not support timestamps subtraction.

Comment: We are using Cloudera-5.3.1/hive-0.13.1-cdh5.3.1. This version does not support?

Comment: @Shash, a version from 3 years ago (6 June, 2014)?... No

Comment: hive> with t as (select 1502802618 as ts1,1502786788 as ts2)
    > select  substr(from_unixtime(to_unix_timestamp('0001-01-01 00:00:00')+(ts1 - ts2)),12)   as diff
    > from    t
    > ;
OK
diff
04:23:50      This query works fine. Need to integrate this with the lag(windowing function). As we need to differentiate between time-stamps in two different rows.

Comment: @Shash, **(1)** comment in the right place **(2)** You are talking about basic SQL, just replace `ts1` and `ts2` with the relevant expressions (column and lag(...) over (...))